# Is there a way to package a Karate test suite into a runnable jar?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, karate

I have been developing a test suite with the Karate framework. I developed a test class that runs all the tests in parallel from the IntelliJ IDE. What I want to do is export my project to a single file that can run all the tests with a click of the mouse, no IDE required. Alas, despite my efforts I have not been able to find a solution, because it seems that you can't run any java classes in src/test as a main class

[Here is my project structure, including the test I want to run as my main class:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwIrg.png)

The class TestParallel should be the main class of my program, but if I try to build an artifact and run the jar file, it can't find the class TestParallel

Comment: tip: don't depend on JUnit, yes has to be in `src/main` and use the `Runner` class. also please start switching to 1.0 https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/1.0-upgrade-guide